# How to use Secedit.exe to find which accounts have permission for SeLockMemoryPrivilege and SeManageVolumePrivilege local security policies?

Tags: windows, security, windows-server

I would like to know how (if possible) to use Secedit.exe to find out which account(s) have permission for the local security policies SeLockMemoryPrivilege and SeManageVolumePrivilege. When I export the system security template using "C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb", only four User Rights security policies are in the template (for each policy, a different line:  = "SID1,SID2,...SIDn"). The two policies I want are not in the four. How do I get them? That is, how do I get the permissions info for SeLockMemoryPrivilege and SeManageVolumePrivilege?

Thanks!

Comment: On my machine, if you don't specify which database to use, the output includes all rights and privileges which have been assigned.  It doesn't include entries that are empty, e.g., SeLockMemoryPrivilege by default isn't assigned to anybody, so it doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: I tried that Harry. I get the same result :(

Comment: And I did confirm that the two policies had entries beforehand.